# Error importing AggregatedClustersCosts from spotinst_sdk2.models.ocean.aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

In my python file, I have this:

```
from spotinst_sdk2.models.ocean.aws import AggregatedClusterCosts
```

...and I am getting the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 4, in
from spotinst_sdk2.models.ocean.aws import AggregatedClusterCosts
ImportError: cannot import name 'AggregatedClusterCosts' from 'spotinst_sdk2.models.ocean.aws' (C:\Users\daz_R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spotinst_sdk2\models\ocean\aws_init_.py)
```

What can I do to fix that?

Thanks in advance

I installed `spotinst_sdk2`  with the next command:  `pip install --upgrade spotinst-sdk2`